# What's the elegant way of writing CombineLatest with conditional arguments?

Tags: arrays, merge, rxjs, combinelatest

In a non-async code, I do the following:

```
    const x = [
        ...(isY ? [Y]: []),
        ...(isZ ? [Z] : [])
    ];
```

How would you elegantly write this structure when `isY` and `isZ` are `Observables<boolean>`, and `x` to be an `Observable<Object[]>`.

I can do this with al kinds of mappings, but nothing looks clean or elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combineLatest` operator is best used when you have multiple, long-lived `observables` that rely on each other for some calculation or determination.
Be aware that `combineLatest` will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value.

You can have a look at the [explanation](https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom#toc-combinelatest-the-go-dutch-operator) for `combineLatest`.

```
const x: Observable<any[]> = combineLatest(isY$, isZ$).pipe(
    map([isY, isZ] => {
        return [
            ...(isY ? [Y]: []),
            ...(isZ ? [Z]: [])
        ]
    })
)
```

EDIT: 
You can also use the combineLatest project-function, so it can even be terser by doing

```
const x: Observable<any[]> = combineLatest(isY$, isZ$, (isY, isZ) => [ 
   ...(isY ? [Y]: []), 
   ...(isZ ? [Z]: []) 
])
```